# The speed of downloading packages in Visual Studio Code is painfully slow

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I open Visual Studio Code, C# has to download packages that it needs in order to work (for example, [OmniSharp](https://www.omnisharp.net/#portfolioModal-vscode)), but just like the title suggests, it's painfully slow to the point that I either forget or just don't want to get any work done.

So with that, is there a way to speed up the process?
If not, is it possible to disable the download?